# Pandas dataframe incorrectly including data type in output

Tags: python, pandas

In iPy Notebook (see below) I am doing a bit of data massage to pull wanted data from a CSV file. I am doing this by creating new pandas dataframes, and I'm having an issue that I have never seen before -- At the end of each new dictionary within a dataframe, the type of data is included.

```
 df_files = glob.glob('/Users/snplabadmin...')

 all_regressors= {'participant':[], 'sooner': [], 'safer':[], 'later':[], 'risky':[]}
#output = {}

for df_file in df_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(df_file)

    participant = df['participant'][0]

    #make sure all response keys are coded as strings
    df['choice_key.keys'] = map(str, df['choice_key.keys']) #convert every item in df['choice_key.keys'] to a string

    #create new column of coded responses
    df['resp']=0  # Initialize to 0 (good for misses, too)
    df['resp'][df['choice_key.keys']=='1'] = 1
    df['resp'][df['choice_key.keys']=='1.0'] = 1  # Left == Sooner/Safer
    df['resp'][df['choice_key.keys']=='2'] = 2
    df['resp'][df['choice_key.keys']=='2.0'] = 2  # Right == Later/Riskier

    #create runs
    run_1 = df[0:36]
    run_2 = df[38:73]
    run_3 = df[74:110]
    run_4 = df[111:147]
    run_5 = df[148:184]
    run_6 = df[185:221]
    runs = [run_1, run_2, run_3, run_4, run_5, run_6]

    #define counter for loop
    counter = 1

    for run in runs:
        counter = counter
        run_numb = participant + str(counter)
        print run_numb
        delays = run[run['delay0_prob1'] == 0] # separate delay trials into dataframe
        probs = run[run['delay0_prob1'] == 1] # separate prob trials into dataframe 

        #parse responses from delay and prob dataframes
        delays_sooner = delays[delays['resp'] == 1]
        #print delays_sooner['ddpd']
        delays_later = delays[delays['resp'] == 2]
        probs_safer = probs[probs['resp'] == 1]
        probs_risky = probs[probs['resp'] == 2]

        sooner = delays_sooner['ResponseTime']
        safer = probs_safer['ResponseTime']
        later = delays_later['ResponseTime']
        risky = probs_risky['ResponseTime']

        all_regressors['sooner'].append(delays_sooner['ResponseTime'])
        all_regressors['safer'].append(probs_safer['ResponseTime'])
        all_regressors['later'].append(delays_later['ResponseTime'])
        all_regressors['risky'].append(probs_risky['ResponseTime'])
        all_regressors['participant'].append(run_numb)

        counter = counter +1
```

A dictionary from 'all_regressors' should only include a list of numbers, but instead I'm seeing:

```
    tdcs_208p1
8     180.00
13     90.00
15      0.25
26     30.00
27     90.00
Name: ddpd, dtype: float64
tdcs_208p2
71    30
Name: ddpd, dtype: float64
tdcs_208p3
Series([], name: ddpd, dtype: float64)
tdcs_208p4
111    180
124    180
127      7
138     90
146    180
Name: ddpd, dtype: float64
tdcs_208p5
153     90
156    180
179     90
Name: ddpd, dtype: float64
tdcs_208p6
210    1
Name: ddpd, dtype: float64
```

Any ideas on why I am getting these extra inputs, and how I can get rid of them? All I want are numbers!

Thanks!!

Comment: This is just the way that the data is printed, it doesn't mean that this will mess up any calculations you want performed, if you want just the values then do `all_regressors[key].values`

Comment: Also this: `df['resp'][df['choice_key.keys']=='1'] = 1` is dodgy and is not guaranteed to work you should use `df.loc[df['choice_key.keys']=='1', 'resp'] = 1` see the docs:http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: the other alternative is to assign the numpy values: `all_regressors['sooner'].append(delays_sooner['ResponseTime'].values)`

Comment: @EdChum Thanks for your help and tips! All fixed :)

Comment: simply below change fixed issue `all_regressors['sooner'].append(delays_sooner['ResponseTime'].values) all_regressors['safer'].append(probs_safer['ResponseTime'].values)
all_regressors['later'].append(delays_later['ResponseTime'].values)
all_regressors['risky'].append(probs_risky['ResponseTime'].values)`

Comment: Please post it as an answer not as a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply below change (.value) fixed issue, thanks Ed! `all_regressors['sooner'].append(delays_sooner['ResponseTime'].values) all_regressors['safer'].append(probs_safer['ResponseTime'].values) all_regressors['later'].append(delays_later['ResponseTime'].values) all_regressors['risky'].append(probs_risky['ResponseTime'].values)`